# Java cannot find .class file, or class

Tags: java, classpath

I have a directory structure thus:

```
project/
       src/
          videoserver/
                     *.java
          storeclient/
                     *.java
       bin/
          videoserver/
                     *.class
          storeclient/
                     *.class
```

My current working directory is `project/src/` and I'm using the command `java -cp "../bin/" videoserver.Main`

This all seems right to me, but Java is telling me it cannot find the class `IVideoServer`. I can see `IVideoServer.class` in the correct folder, and it seems able to find the `Main` class just fine.

**What could be causing Java to be unable to find `IVideoServer`?**

---

The method that appears to be causing the problem is this one

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try 
    {
        VideoServer Server = new VideoServer();
        videoserver.IVideoServer stub = (IVideoServer)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Server, 0);

        // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("server-url", 9090);
        registry.bind("VideoServer", stub);
        System.err.println("Server ready");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have already compiled all of the classes involved with `javac`.

---

This is the full exception and stack trace as it is returned to me

Server exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: videoserver.IVideoServer
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: videoserver.IVideoServer
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at videoserver.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: videoserver.IVideoServer
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: videoserver.IVideoServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(LoaderHandler.java:711)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:655)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(LoaderHandler.java:592)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:628)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(RMIClassLoader.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(MarshalInputStream.java:238)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1530)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1492)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
... 12 more
```

Comment: .. having no light detecting mechanisms (i.e. eyes)?

Comment: Show us your code, please, especially the line that Java is complaining about. Is there an import problem?

Comment: in which word is Java you telling, it cannot find the class?

Comment: it's a bad project structure anyways, *.java should go to the target folder

Comment: Yes, Java is throwing the good old `ClassNotFound` exception. I'll update my original post.

Comment: You're right, @OlivierRefalo, I've tidied it up some. Updated in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

From the src folder, have you tried `java -cp .  videoserver.Main`  ??

try this, `javap videoserver.Main`

Comment: make sure bin is in the CLASSPATH, then try this, javap videoserver.Main

Comment: This gave me gave me `Compiled from "Main.java"`, the class signature, constructor signature and main signature. Was this the expected output?

Comment: yes, it means the .class can be found. Could you provide the complete ClassNotFound exception... might just be VideoServer that is not in the classpath.

Comment: I've added the exception and stack trace in to my original post, because it's far too long for a comment.

Comment: ok, looks like the jar, or the set of jars containing videoserver.IVideoServer are missing. check your classpath

Comment: There are no jars involved in this. There are only 5 files involved, which are all in that folder. Is there any reason why the class path might contain one file in the folder, but not another?